# how to write multiple foreach statement at once

Tags: php

In my coding i want to display all records from donate table and **donation_date** from tbl_user table. i tried to execute both statement by foreach ......

```
**<?php foreach($people as $donors and $donor as $donors): ?>**
```

But it is invalid and i dont know the valid one what i can implement. thanks in advance.

HERE is two table in phpmyadmin

tbl_user

[image]

donate

[image]

**here is my code**

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mypro_bms;host=localhost', 'root', '');
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
  $q = $_GET['q'];
  $statement = $db->prepare("select * from donate where passport_IC like :passport_IC");
  $statement->execute([
    ':passport_IC' => '%' . $q .'%'

  ]);

} else {
  $statement = $db->prepare('select * from donate');
  $statement->execute();
}
$people = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
 ?>
 <?php

$statement = $db->prepare('select donation_date from tbl_user');
$statement->execute();
$donor = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

?>

<table class="table table-bordered">
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Passport/IC</th>
            <th>Blood Group</th>
            <th>Blood Bag Type</th>



          </tr>
          <?php foreach($people as $donors and $donor as $donors): ?>
            <tr>
               <td><center><b><font color="black"><?= $donors->id; ?></font></b></center></td>
               <td><center><b><font color="black"><?= $donors->passport_ic; ?></font></b></center></td>
               <td><center><b><font color="black"><?= $donors->blood_group; ?></font></b></center></td>
               <td><center><b><font color="black"><?= $donors->blood_bag; ?></font></b></center></td>
               <td><center><b><font color="black"><?= $donors->donation_date; ?></font></b></center></td>
              <td>
              <a href="delete.php?id=<?= $donors->id; ?>">Delete</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          <?php endforeach; ?>

        </table>
```

Comment: I would guess if you showed us the schema for these 2 tables you could get the data from the database in one simple query

Comment: Currently, the data you retrieve would not be able to properly processed. You woudl not get the correct data shown with the correct user

Comment: its really appreciable. but just i want to know how i need to write the foreach statement for above code

Comment: Well you can NEST a foreach inside a foreach. But in this case it will just generate nonsense

Comment: okay got it. so is there any other way. as i am new in  coding so asking for easy way. and many many thanks

Comment: `foreach($people as $key=>$value){
     $value["property1"]
}` 
youll want to do some echo on the actualy values though

Comment: its not working

Comment: Of course its not

Comment: show us a `show create table donate;` and `show create table tbl_user;`

Comment: sorry for being late. i already edited my post you can check

Comment: So `tbluser.passport_IC` and `donate.passport_ic` are the columns that link these 2 tables

Comment: in tbl_user table passport_ic is primary key and non increment and in donate passport_ic is not primary key and non increment. so can i link with passport_ic?

Comment: So if there are no columns that match between these 2 tables the data is basically unusable

Answer (score 0):

To me, it sounds like you should be structuring the database query to gather the info from both tables at the same time. They should be linked somehow, usually by an id, maybe in this case `donor_id` but I don't know the schema for your tables. I can give you an example of what a simple JOIN looks like that might work for you, again assuming your tables are linked by `donor_id`:

```
SELECT donate.*, tbl_user.donation_date 
FROM donate 
    INNER JOIN tbl_user ON donate.passport_ic=tbl_user.passport_IC;
```

Take the result of this query and lool through that. Should work out for you.

Comment: So it looks like they are linked by `passport_ic`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: yeah but in tbl_user table passport_ic is primary key and non increment and in   donate passport_ic is not primary key and non increment